# show console window from WinForms program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms program. If a user starts it from the command line and passes an invalid parameter, how could I display error information in the console window?

Comment: In windows you can specify arguments to pass to a program via a shortcut. If the shortcut parameters are incorrect, where would the error message be displayed? I.e. why wouldn't you either display the error message in your window / ignore the parameters (or log to event viewer / log file)?

Answer (score 4):

Here is example how to display message to command line if bad parameter is passed to winform application:

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //if parameter -window is passed - opens main form, else displays Bad params message
        if(args[0] == "-window")
            Application.Run(new main());
        else
        {
            //Attach console process
            AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
            Console.WriteLine("Bad params");
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.csharp411.com/console-output-from-winforms-application/

Answer (score 1):

You could output the information using the Console.WriteLine(message) method.

Comment: But my App is Winform not Console.

Answer (score 0):

Your WinForms app could raise a pop up, like a message box, that shows the error.

If the application is running in unattended mode as part of a batch file, you could write to the Event Log, or to a custom log file created by the application.

The other answers that tell you to use Console.WriteLine are also great if your batch command redirects output to a file, such as...

myApp.exe >> errors.txt

this appends the console to the error.txt file...